# How to chmod without root account?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, root, sudoers

I don't have root account.
I made mistake with my /etc/sudoers files.

I changed mode my /etc/sudoers files to 777

and then, my 'sudo' command has not started work..

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

someone said try to use **pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers**,
but it ask me root Password..

and I can't reboot my server..
what can I do. help me please.

Comment: Have you tried this @Eunji

https://askubuntu.com/a/73872/815342

Comment: @Kiran I didnt edut flies inside.. I just changed chmod. So Maybe It will not work...

Comment: You have in effect lost root permissions to the server and are now looking to change the permissions on a file owned by root. You are going to have to reboot into recovery mode and change the permissions that way

Comment: Anyone find the solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.